How to insert Rocket.chat Omnichannel livechat in iframe without open/close button?
I want to insert livechat in iframe on my site without open/close button (only support onichannel chat layout).
tryed somthing like this:
'use client';
import React from 'react';

export const Support = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-semibold mb-10">Support</h1>

      <iframe
        src="https://chat.exemple.com/livechat"
        title="Chat"
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '800px', zIndex: '1300' }}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

but it look like this
enter image description here
So maybe you can help me to solve this.
expected to get rocket chat live chat window in my iframe without button

SOLVED
'use client';
import React from 'react';

export const Support = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-semibold mb-10">Поддержка</h1>

      <iframe
        src="https://lala.com/livechat?mode=popout"
        title="Чат"
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '800px', zIndex: '1300' }}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

Solution: just add ?mode=popout after your live chat link
